# Cakephp can not connect to Sqlserver Express 2012

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp

I got this issue:

> CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.
>
> Database connection "Sqlserver" is missing, or could not be created.

Details of what I've had so far:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlserver',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost\MSSQLSERVER',
    //'login' => 'root',
    //'password' => '',
    'database' => 'Northwind',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

and in my xampp\php\php.ini I had this

```
[pdo_sqlsrv]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll //this file exists in xampp\php\ext
pdo_sqlsrv.log_severity=-1
```

And I have a Northwind database as well.

So what causes the issue and what would be the solution?
Longing to your helps, guys. 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart Apache after enabling the extension? Create a simple phpinfo page and make sure that the extension is being loaded. You should be able to see it in the PDO section also make sure you are loading the correct driver for you PHP version.

[image]